# One interesting comma

Tags: punctuation

Now I'm defending my work devoted to one interesting comma, found by me personally, which I first thought was simply wrong, but then I fell in love with it, and I still am.

I need your assessment of what I think is correct about that "super" comma.

▪︎ Essential clauses cannot, as you know, be divided with commas, but this comma is put with them at the end, thereby it lets us know when the auxiliary, which is divided from its subject by a long essential clause, begins(it should help with reading); however, this comma is optional and doesn't have to be used.

Example: The cat running across the street over there[,] seems mysterious.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Am I right about that found-by-me comma? About the fact that it's optional but exists anyway?

Comment: @Винни-мыслитель When asked for clarification, please edit your question to include it. Don't bury essential information in comments. Thanks.

Comment: There are various relevant questions. mostly on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305901/at-what-point-should-i-add-a-comma-after-a-relative-clause https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21988/using-comma-with-a-relative-clause https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/218521/do-i-need-to-use-definite-article-and-commas-in-a-defining-relative-clause https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67800/the-use-or-omission-of-commas-round-relative-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Your example is grammatically incorrect because the comma separates the subject of the verb from the verb itself.

- The cat seems mysterious.

You cannot put a comma between *cat* and *seems.* The additional clause "running across the street over there" does not change that.

There **may** be a subtle pause or inflection at that point when reading/saying that sentence, but that is what is inserted to aid understanding. To make it a comma when writing such a sentence is not correct<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> This sentence is a case in point. There may be a subtle pause before the word *is,* but you can't put a comma there.

Comment: But we can, for example, separate the subject from the predicate with a non-essential-information clause, for instance: My cat, which is highly beloved by me, is so magical.                 Why can't we do the same in my case?

Comment: @Винни-мыслитель Because you have only one comma. And as the "running across the street over there" is a restrictive clause, it's not non-essential information so you can't set it off with two commas. I could add that to the answer I suppose.

Comment: I can't separate it with two commas, but I can separate it with one, which is according to my presumption, right?

Comment: No, one comma is wrong: you cannot separate the subject from the verb, as the answer says. Two commas are wrong: it's a restrictive clause which can't be offset with commas. You can't use any commas in that sentence.